# Quantum algorithm encrypting classical data

Tags: public-key, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography

Are there schemes for encrypting classical ciphertext using quantum algorithms? Specifically, if a public key system exists for classical data, and classical ciphertexts, can this scheme be implemented by quantum algorithms (A quantum algorithm implementing classical public key algorithms)?

Comment: What are Quantum algorithm for you ?

Comment: Any kind, Shors' algorithm, Grovers search(if usable in such a scheme), BB84 key scheme, or even adiabatic quantum algorithms that implement a public key encryption scheme.

Comment: As a quantum computer can simulate any classical computer in polynomial time, a quantum computer can perform all classical public key encryption schemes.

Comment: There's a more interesting question potentially lurking here, which may or may not be what you meant to ask: Are there cryptosystems that can be _efficiently_ implemented by a quantum computer (measured in qubits and qubit operations, under the premise that they some day become efficiently implementable), but not by a classical computer (measured in bits and bit operations)?

Comment: Given space available, the question, simply put  firstly -  before efficiency , and robustness of qubit operations come into play, is that of whether any scheme that of public key, or private key, or hashing  based, can any of them be implemented on a qubit  based quantum cryptosystem, measured in qubits, and qubit operations?

Comment: to follow this line we come to the question, are there cryptosystems that can be efficiently implemented by a quantum computer given there is a high degree of efficiency, and robustness of qubits\(and qubit operations), after all if one could implement the RSA scheme efficiently, on a quantum computer it would be no mean achievement, in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a quantum computer can implement any classical algorithm.

This can be easily proven, because [quantum computers are Turing-complete](https://www.quora.com/Are-quantum-computers-Turing-complete). And if a computer is Turing complete then it can, by definition, [run any classical algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness):

> A universal Turing machine can be used to simulate any Turing machine and by extension the computational aspects of any possible real-world computer.

And that's - as far as I can see - QED.

Comment: This is a bit of a cop out.  Presumably the question is about algorithms that couldn't run just as well on a classical computer!  For example, imagine an algorithm that somehow uses Shor's algorithm as a subroutine.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage If it was about speeding up classical algorithms then the question should have stated that. The only question I can see is if classical algorithms can be run on a quantum computer and this does answer this. If the answer is not complete then the *user* is free to comment. And you are of course free to supply your own answer, ask for clarifications to the author or indeed ask a new question. The word "specifically" (i.e. specifying the question further) followed by "can this scheme be implemented by quantum algorithms" doesn't leave that much room IMHO.